# How to stop optimization of a circuit during transpiling in web-interface of IBM Q?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, optimization, qasm

I was playing with approximation of gates with Clifford+T group on IBM Q. Everything works well on simulator, however, when I tried to run my circuit on actual quantum processor, a transpiler optimized circuit so only one $U3$ gate remained. Hence, I was not able to run my original circuit and assess effect of decoherence etc based on depth of the circuit.

To given an example, my original circuit is

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

h q[0];
s q[0];
t q[0];
sdg q[0];
h q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

After transpiling (on IBM Q Armonk), the resulting QASM code is as follows:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

u3(-0.7853981633974483, 1.5707963267948966, 4.71238898038469) q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

I tried to add barriers before first `h q[0];` and after last `h q[0];` to prevent optimizer from working, however, without success.

I understand that basic gates on IBM Q are $I$, $U1$, $U2$ and $U3$ and that $H$, $S$, $S^\dagger$ and $T$ are eventually impleted by these $U$ gates.

**However, is it possible to avoid optimization so that the original number of gates is preserved?** In other words, Hadamard will be presented by one $U3$ gate, phase gate and $T$ by one $U1$ gate each etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the web based composer there is currently no way to adjust the optimization level. As a workaround, you can put a barrier before and after each gate. This will prevent them from being joined.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

When you transpile (either when calling `execute` or `transpile`), you should be able to set `optimization_level=0` so the transpiler only maps the qubits to the backend. [You can see an example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWJbfyE9Vi4).